# Programmatically set a textbox linked to a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel you can insert a `TextBox` shapes object and link it to a cell's value by selecting the shape, then selecting the formula bar and clicking the cell whose value you'd like to have shown in the TextBox.

When I record a macro doing this, I get the following.

```
Sub RecordedMacro()
'
' RecordedMacro Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 12.3, 101.55, _
        40.5).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Formula = "=Sheet1!R7C5"
    Range("D16").Select
End Sub
```

If I simply re-run this macro manually, the macro breaks at the `Selection.Formula` step with the error `Run-time error '1004': Unable to set the Formula property of the TextBox class`

**How can I accomplish this task (assign cell value to TextBox) programmatically that Excel allows you to do from the UI?**

For reference, this is what the XML shows when you link the TextBox manually and save the file.  It would be monstrously difficult to build this xml manually.

```
<cdr:sp macro="" textlink="Sheet1!$D$7">
      <cdr:nvSpPr>
        <cdr:cNvPr id="7" name="TextBox 6">
          <a:extLst xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
            <a:ext uri="{FF2B5EF4-FFF2-40B4-BE49-F238E27FC236}">
              <a16:creationId xmlns:a16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/main" id="{A138082B-AC53-4E42-86F7-A28CF4BF4089}" />
            </a:ext>
          </a:extLst>
        </cdr:cNvPr>
        <cdr:cNvSpPr txBox="1" />
      </cdr:nvSpPr>
      <cdr:spPr>
        <a:xfrm xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
          <a:off x="622935" y="1184910" />
          <a:ext cx="2667000" cy="1200150" />
        </a:xfrm>
        <a:prstGeom xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" prst="rect">
          <a:avLst />
        </a:prstGeom>
      </cdr:spPr>
      <cdr:txBody>
        <a:bodyPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" vertOverflow="clip" wrap="square" rtlCol="0" />
        <a:lstStyle xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" />
        <a:p xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
          <a:fld id="{3CDA77B5-21A6-4C86-91DA-7A407717D285}" type="TxLink">
            <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="1100" b="0" i="0" u="none" strike="noStrike">
              <a:solidFill>
                <a:srgbClr val="000000" />
              </a:solidFill>
              <a:latin typeface="Droid Sans" />
              <a:ea typeface="Droid Sans" />
              <a:cs typeface="Droid Sans" />
            </a:rPr>
            <a:t>This is much longer text</a:t>
          </a:fld>
          <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" sz="1100" />
        </a:p>
      </cdr:txBody>
    </cdr:sp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Formula property of the TextBox object to link to a cell.  By the way, there's no need to do any activating and selecting.

```
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart
    .Shapes.AddTextbox msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, 12.3, 101.55, 40.5
    .TextBoxes(.TextBoxes.Count).Formula = "=Sheet1!E7"
End With
```